# Laravel - Fullcalendar doesn't load but show html code

Tags: php, laravel, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar package in my laravel project, I think that works but I don't know why don´t show the calendar but shows html code in my view.

```
<div id="calendar-TcJ9C2VA"></div> 
<script> $(document).ready(function()
{ $('#calendar-TcJ9C2VA').fullCalendar({"header":{"left":"prev,next today","center":"title","right":"month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"},"eventLimit":true,"firstDay":1,"events":[{"id":1,"title":"moradia","allDay":false,"start":"2017-03-29T00:00:00+00:00","end":"2017-03-30T08:00:00+00:00"}]}); });
</script>
```

sources

```
<script src={{ asset('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js') }}></script>
    <script src={{ asset('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js') }}></script>
    <script src={{ asset('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.js') }}></script>
    <script src={{ asset('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.css') }}></script>
    <script src={{ asset('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.print.css') }}></script>
```

in console gives me errors, but I already changes jquery/moment sources, and always same errors.

[image]

EDIT: now I have this errors and same html code in view
[image]

Comment: i have tried, same problems

Comment: i have changed css files to <link> and same problems

Comment: i think the problems are in js files cause i got the two first problems in last photo. but i don´t know why

Answer (score 0):

First you should import css like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset("//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.css")}}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset("//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.print.css")}}" />
```

second, try to import the lang js to your site, after the fullcalendar js import.

```
<script src="{{ asset('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/lang-all.js') }}"></script>
```

And I suggest you to use the latest [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/download/).

I hope I could help! I tried out **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fp4tcs35/)** and it works.

**Edit:**

The other problem is that the `{{asset('#'}}` **does not return between the double quote** so you shuold define like this: `"{{asset('#'}}"`